# Extracting all nlp entities to another column

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, text-processing

I'm trying to extract all entities to another column in my dataset.

I've tried this code below on a small portion of my full dataset and it works, but once I put in my whole dataset I get the following error:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

```
def all_ents(v):
    return [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in nlp(v).ents]

dt['Entities'] = dt['text'].apply(lambda v: all_ents(v))
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, `dt['Entities'] = dt['text'].astype(str).apply(lambda v: all_ents(v))` would solve it.

Comment: I also just tried this: dt['text'].fillna('', inplace=True)
print(dt['text'].map(len).max()) . It worked well too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `text` column contains some float values or `np.nan`s.

It is safer to cast all the values of that column to a string:

```py
dt['Entities'] = dt['text'].astype(str).apply(lambda v: all_ents(v))
#                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```